# Selenium Java. Unable to find web elements in pop up window

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to test out this sign-in page on FaceBook. In this page, there is a signup button that once clicked, a pop up window will appear. I cannot locate any of the elements in this pop up. I tried to print out all the window handles but there is only one windowHandle. I also couldn't find any new frame to switch to. Please help!

Here is the screenshot of the popup:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    
    WebElement newAcctButton=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Create new acount']"));
    newAcctButton.click();
    
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"u_1k_b_yc\"]"))));
    
    WebElement firstName= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"u_1f_b_rc\"]"));
    firstName.sendKeys("thao");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the below xpath for the username field and I also try to change the XPath of the waitfuncn.

(//div[contains(text(),'Create a new account')]/parent::div/following-sibling::div/child::div/child::div/div/child::form/child::div/descendant::div[5]/child::div[1])[1]
```

Comment: sorry, i dont understand this xpath.

Comment: It's an Xpath Axes I was written, pls let me know whether it's working or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didnt work. The console printed out invalid syntax.